# Selenium 3.0 gecko driver and marionette driver

Tags: selenium, geckodriver, firefox-marionette

How are GeckoDriver and Marionette driver related to each other and how do they work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marionette is the automation/control API provided by Firefox.  GeckoDriver provides a WebDriver (https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) compliant endpoint that then talks to Firefox via Marionette - i.e. it translates between WebDriver and Marionette.